# Fill missing values by finding matches in another column

Tags: r

[image]

```
# generate data
df <- data.frame(
  QuestionId = c(rep(NA, 16)),
  AltQuestionId = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, NA, 8, 10, NA, NA, 14, NA, 16, NA, 18, 20),
  AltTakerId = c(7, 13, 10, 15, 17, NA, 8, 11, NA, NA, 25, NA, 29, NA, 35, 29)
)
df$QuestionId[c(6, 9, 10, 12, 14)] <- c(1, 6, 2, 6, 4)
df$TakerId <- NA # a column of NAs
```

I have no idea how to fill the `TakerID` column as explained in the Figure above.

The variables `QuestionID` and `AltQuestionID` are the same. 
Also the variables `TakerID` and `AltTakerID` are the same.

The purpose is to associate `QuestionID` with `TakerID`.

Output wanted:

```
> df
   QuestionId AltQuestionId AltTakerId TakerId
1          NA             1          7      NA
2          NA             2         13      NA
3          NA             4         10      NA
4          NA             5         15      NA
5          NA             6         17      NA
6           1            NA         NA       7
7          NA             8          8      NA
8          NA            10         11      NA
9           6            NA         NA      17
10          2            NA         NA      13
11         NA            14         25      NA
12          6            NA         NA      17
13         NA            16         29      NA
14          4            NA         NA      10
15         NA            18         35      NA
16         NA            20         29      NA
```

Comment: When asking for help, it's better if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the desired output for that input. Pictures of data aren't particularly helpful because we don't want to re-type it all just to test.

Comment: @Phil pairwise equality testing won't work for this. @giulio use `match()`.

Comment: Removed my erroneous comment.

Comment: @Gregor could you be more specific?

Comment: A few notes on using Stack Overflow: (1) it's good to wait a while before accepting an answer (a couple hours to a day) so you can see what else comes along. (2) Try to describe your question in the title. You probably wouldn't have drawn as many downvotes with a title like *"Fill missing values by finding matches in another column"*, and (3) share data in a copy/pasteable way. The data that Milan created in his answer (and I used) should have been created by you and posted in the question. That way potential answerers have a good place to start. (This also would have kept the downvotes away)

Comment: @Gregor thank you for the suggestions, I'm new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner with `match`:

```
df$TakerId = df$AltTakerId[match(df$QuestionId, df$AltQuestionId)]
df
#    QuestionId AltQuestionId AltTakerId TakerId
# 1          NA             1          7      NA
# 2          NA             2         13      NA
# 3          NA             4         10      NA
# 4          NA             5         15      NA
# 5          NA             6         17      NA
# 6           1            NA         NA       7
# 7          NA             8          8      NA
# 8          NA            10         11      NA
# 9           6            NA         NA      17
# 10          2            NA         NA      13
# 11         NA            14         25      NA
# 12          6            NA         NA      17
# 13         NA            16         29      NA
# 14          4            NA         NA      10
# 15         NA            18         35      NA
# 16         NA            20         29      NA
```

---

Using Milan's nicely provided data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  QuestionId = c(rep(NA, 16)),
  AltQuestionId = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, NA, 8, 10, NA, NA, 14, NA, 16, NA, 18, 20),
  AltTakerId = c(7, 13, 10, 15, 17, NA, 8, 11, NA, NA, 25, NA, 29, NA, 35, 29)
)
df$QuestionId[c(6, 9, 10, 12, 14)] <- c(1, 6, 2, 6, 4)
```

Comment: Nice one, although maybe mention that this is not going to work if `AltQuestionId != unique(AltQuestionId)` or if `is.na(AltQuestionId) != is.na(AltTakerId)`?

Comment: Since the what should be done in those cases isn't at all clear, I'll just leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you want to deal with the fact that there are duplicate values in `QuestionId` (two 6s) but if

- a) there are as many entries in `AltQuestionID` for each unique `QuestionId` value as there are instances of the given `QuestionId` value, or
- b) there is only one instance of each unique `QuestionId` value in `AltQuestionId` and you want `TakerId` to duplicate the `AltTakerId` for `QuestionId` duplicates, then

this should work:

```
# generate data
df <- data.frame(
  QuestionId = c(rep(NA, 16)),
  AltQuestionId = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, NA, 8, 10, NA, NA, 14, NA, 16, NA, 18, 20),
  AltTakerId = c(7, 13, 10, 15, 17, NA, 8, 11, NA, NA, 25, NA, 29, NA, 35, 29)
)
df$QuestionId[c(6, 9, 10, 12, 14)] <- c(1, 6, 2, 6, 4)
df$TakerId <- NA # a column of NAs

# for each unique value of QuestionId (i) put the value of AltTakerId
# that corresponds to the row where AltQuestionId equals i into the row
# of TakerId for which QuestionId equals i
for (i in na.omit(unique(df$QuestionId))) {
  df$TakerId[which(df$QuestionId == i)] <- df$AltTakerId[which(df$AltQuestionId == i)]
}
```

This gives:

```
> df
   QuestionId AltQuestionId AltTakerId TakerId
1          NA             1          7      NA
2          NA             2         13      NA
3          NA             4         10      NA
4          NA             5         15      NA
5          NA             6         17      NA
6           1            NA         NA       7
7          NA             8          8      NA
8          NA            10         11      NA
9           6            NA         NA      17
10          2            NA         NA      13
11         NA            14         25      NA
12          6            NA         NA      17
13         NA            16         29      NA
14          4            NA         NA      10
15         NA            18         35      NA
16         NA            20         29      NA
```